# Can you pass a variable as a parameter to Powershell's Select-String

Tags: string, powershell

I have a multiline string that I want to filter with 'Select-String'

```
echo $foo
bar
buzz
```

If I use select-string with a string parameter, it works fine

```
echo $foo | Select-String 'bar'
bar
```

If I try and replace the string selection with a variable, nothing is returned.

```
$variable = 'bar'
echo $foo | Select-String $variable
```

How do you pass a variable to Select-String ?

Here is every syntax I've tried

```
echo $foo | Select-String $variable
echo $foo | Select-String "$variable"
echo $foo | Select-String "$(variable)"
echo $foo | Select-String "$($variable)"
echo $foo | Select-String $($variable)
```

$variable is a string

```
$variable.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: Using a variable works for me: `$needle = 'Import' ; @( 'fu', 'bar', 'Import' ) | sls $needle`. Check that `$foo` actually contains the value in `$variable`. Check you're actually piping something to `Select-String`. Validate all your assumptions.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, $foo isn't really a string like I thought, it is actually an object.

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable works for me:

```
> $needle = 'Import' ; @( 'fu', 'bar', 'Import' ) | Select-String $needle

Import
```

Check that `$foo` actually contains the value in `$variable`. Check that you're actually piping something to `Select-String` (sometimes I forget to type a `|` character). Validate all your assumptions.